# Getting null reference for posted viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this GET

```
  public ActionResult Add(int productId, int categoryId, int styleId)
        {
          ...
```

and this post:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Add(OrderDetailsViewModel thisWindowModel)
 {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      return View(thisWindowModel);
    }
```

In my view Im getting a null reference exception here:

```
  <h2>Order Details:@Model.StyleName</h2>
```

even though i have this in the view

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.StyleName)
```

I have debugged it, and can see this comes as a string expected.

When i remove the line completely from my view im still getting a null reference exception....

Any ideas? its not making sense to me!

[image]

Thanks

Update:

Get method is:

```
   public ActionResult Add(int productId, int categoryId, int styleId)
{
AccountInfo objAccData = new AccountInfo();
AccountData thisAccInfo = objAccData.GetInfo("ABC");//TempData["FakeAccNo"].ToString());
CheckSupplier objCheckFrameSupp = new CheckSupplier(styleId, thisAccInfo.DepNo);
int FrameSupp = objCheckFrameSupp.GetFrameSupplier();


WindowColoursFromStyle objColItems = new WindowColoursFromStyle(styleId);


WindowsOptionsFromStyleSupplier objStyleOps = new WindowsOptionsFromStyleSupplier(styleId, FrameSupp, categoryId);

var repo = new ProductsRepository();
var style = repo.GetStyle(styleId);
var productCategory = repo.GetProductsCategory(categoryId);
var product = repo.GetProduct(productId);
var salesOrderId = SessionData.SalesOrderId;

return View(new OrderDetailsViewModel(salesOrderId, "Add")
{
    StyleName = style.Name,
    MinimumHeight = style.Minimum_Height,
    MinimumWidth = style.Minimum_Width,
    MaximumWidth = style.Maximum_Width,
    MaximumHeight = style.Maximum_Height,
    External_Image_Path = style.External_Image_Path,
    Category = productCategory,
    Product = product,
    InternalColours = objColItems.InternalColours,
    ExternalColours = objColItems.ExternalColours,
    CillOptions = objStyleOps.CillOptions,
    AddOnBottomOptions = objStyleOps.AddOnsOptions,
    AddOnTopOptions = objStyleOps.AddOnsOptions,
    AddOnLeftOptions = objStyleOps.AddOnsOptions,
    AddOnRightOptions = objStyleOps.AddOnsOptions,
    NoTransoms = objStyleOps.NoTransoms,
    NoDummyTransoms = objStyleOps.NoDummyTransoms,
    NoMullions = objStyleOps.NoMullions,
    NoDummyMullions = objStyleOps.NoDummyMullions,
    GlassUnits = objStyleOps.GlassUnits,
    GlassTypes = objStyleOps.GlassOptions,
    HasOpener = objStyleOps.HasOpeners,
    Handles = objStyleOps.HandleOptions,
    Lock = objStyleOps.LockOptions,
    Stay = objStyleOps.StayOptions,
    FrameThicknessBottom = objStyleOps.FrameThicknessOptions,
    FrameThicknessTop = objStyleOps.FrameThicknessOptions,
    FrameThicknessLeft = objStyleOps.FrameThicknessOptions,
    FrameThicknessRight = objStyleOps.FrameThicknessOptions,
    MullionThickness = objStyleOps.MullionThicknessOptions,
    TransomThickness = objStyleOps.TransomThinknessOptions,
    SashThinkness = objStyleOps.SashThinknessOptions,
    FrameVent = objStyleOps.VentOptions,
    SashVent = objStyleOps.VentOptions,
    WindowStyleID = styleId,
    AccountNumber ="BTCA",// TempData["FakeAccNo"].ToString(),
    DepotNumber = thisAccInfo.DepNo,
    FrameSupplier = FrameSupp,
    FrameNumber = 1,// (int)TempData["FrameNumber"],
    DripBars = objStyleOps.DripBarOptions,
    DrainageOptions = objStyleOps.DrainageOptions,
    RestrictorOptions = objStyleOps.RestrictorOptions,
    ReinforcingTypes = objStyleOps.ReinforcingTypes,
    ReinforcingRules = objStyleOps.ReinforcingRules,
    IsDoor = objStyleOps.isDoor,
        KickPlateOptions = objStyleOps.KickPlateOptions
    });
}
```

view top few lines  is esentially....

```
@model ViewModel.OrderDetailsViewModel



<div class="row heading-row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @*<h2>Order Details:@(Model.StyleName)</h2>*@
    </div>


</div>

@Html.Partial("_OrderDetailsForm",Model)
```

This is a form with a load of selects/dropdowns essentially,

partial view starts as:

```
    @model ViewModel.OrderDetailsViewModel



@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.FormType, "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
```

Comment: Please add the code for `OrderDetailsViewModel`. Also your full action and view.

Comment: How do you use "int productId, int categoryId, int styleId", parameters? And share return section of get method, please

Comment: How you have defined model in the view? Post the starting(top) few lines of your view and also the name to file

Comment: @JhoonBey I've added get method to show how they're use

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Add OrderDetailsViewModel like parameter to GET action. It is a model that sended from POST action:

```
public ActionResult Add(int productId, int categoryId, int styleId, OrderDetailsViewModel modelComesFromPostAction)
{
  if(modelComesFromPostAction == null)
  {
    //your GET action code will get here.
  }
  else
  {
     return View(modelComesFromPostAction);
  }   
}
```